# How do I link a library in cmake?

Tags: cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

(excuse my english)

I am a new with ROS, I am trying to build a node for a driver, the problem is that I need to use an externe library that does the communication staff, how can tell the compiler to use this library in CMakeLists ?
normally if I want to use this library I will do:

g++ -g -Wall main_foo.cpp other.cpp **lib/dmclnx.a -Idmclnxlib** -o run_foo

I have already read the tutorial for CMakeLists and Manifest . Thanks for help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10543/how-do-i-link-a-library-in-cmake?/) by [Anas](https://answers.ros.org/users/736/anas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2011-07-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Let's say you have a library called `libfoo` located in `/usr/local/lib` and you want to link it with a node you're building called `my_node`. Put the following in your CMakeLists.txt:

```
# set the path to the library folder
link_directories(/usr/local/lib)

# link the libraries to the executable
target_link_libraries (my_node foo)
```

(`/usr/local/lib` is probably in your environment path already, so the first line might be unnecessary)

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2011-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zweistein](https://answers.ros.org/users/4023/zweistein/) on 2013-11-25**:
I included the lines suggested above and generated the RailwayImageProcess.so lib in /usr/local/lib:
`target_link_libraries(railDetect RailwayImageProcess) rosbuild_add_executable(railDetect src/main.cpp)`

but i get this error for make . :

`CLinking CXX executable bin/railDetect /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lRailwayImageProcess collect2: ld returned 1 exit status make[2]: *** [bin/railDetect] Error 1 make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/railDetect.dir/all] Error 2 make: *** [all] Error 2`

**Comment by [bergercookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/25299/bergercookie/) on 2016-04-05**:
I think you first have to issue the add_executable directive and then link against any libraries.

**Comment by [bergercookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/25299/bergercookie/) on 2016-04-05**:
Also, including the prefix (lib) or the suffix (.so/.a/.la) doesn't affect the link_directories or target_link_libraries commands.